# What term or terms are used for "at home worker"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice

What term or terms are used for "at home worker" or "remote position"?

Some examples of desired usage include:

> I work out of my home.
>
> These days, it's hard to find a seat at the coffee shop due to all the people who work from home taking up the seats.
>
> I'm looking for a remote position with a company.

Answer (score 2):

The term I usually hear is 재택 근무.

So you could say:

> 저는 요즘 재택근무중입니다 These days I'm working from home.